# Learning RUP: How to start?

Tags: rational-unified-process

I would like to learn RUP...

what are your suggestions?  How to start? which resources? .....

Comment: What's your motivation for this? Are you looking to pad your resume? Is your company forcing you to do RUP? Do you think it will help your software development process? Are you a team lead, member or a one man project?

Comment: There's really only a small handful of cases where RUP is adequate nowadays, you better have a really good reason to use it, or you'll start crying because of all the documents...

Comment: @Carl: unfortunately, none of them, just curiosity!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stay away from it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few introducing words you find in [Rational Unified Process Best Practices](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/1000/1251/1251_bestpractices_TP026B.pdf)

A good starting point is [IBM Rational](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/)

Answer (score 7):

Curiosity is enough reason to learn something new ...

First start with those articles : How people misunderstand RUP, what may wrong with it...

- Larman,Kruchten,Bittner, How to Fail with the Rational Unified Process [Read Online](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~cianca/wwwpages/ids/letture/RUP.pdf)
- Ivar Jacobson,Yes, RUP is my baby [“the baby needs correction"]  [Read Online](http://blog.ivarjacobson.com/yes-rup-is-my-baby/)

Then to understand a light-weight version of RUP read the following(s)

- Kruchten, "A Software Development Process for a Team of One [Read Online](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb02/ProcessForOneFeb02.pdf)

Now you are ready to get more insight....RUP is iterative development process...Sou have to undestand iterative development first...For those read/watch followings:

- Larman, Basili, Iterative and Incremental Development: A Brief History [Read Online](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/misc/history-of-iterative-larman-and-basili-ieee-computer.pdf)
- Larman [Sample chapter from Applying UML & Patterns Chapter 2:  Agile Iterative and Evolutionary ]   [Read Online](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch2-applying-agile-iterative-evolutionary.pdf)
- IJI Consulting, "Why Iterate? Understanding the Essentials of Iterative Development"     [Watch at Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msBo-1qpJCs)
- IJI Consulting, "Are you ready for Iterative Development" [Watch at youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCu-Ogg3Zuc)

RUP is generally use-case driven development process [ it must not be "use case" driven,but generally it is ]...So learn about use cases...For those read followings:

- Larman [Sample chapter from Applying UML & Patterns Chapter 2: Chapter 6: Use Cases ]  [Read Online](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch6-applying-evolutionary-use-cases.pdf)
- Ellen Gottesdiener, Top Ten Ways Project Teams Misuse Use Cases [I]  [Read Online](http://ebgconsulting.com/Pubs/Articles/Top10MisusesOfUseCasesPart2-Gottesdiener.pdf)
- Ellen Gottesdiener, Top Ten Ways Project Teams Misuse Use Cases [II] [Read Online][10](http://ebgconsulting.com/Pubs/Articles/Top10MisusesOfUseCasesPart2-Gottesdiener.pdf)
- Ellen Gottesdiener, "Use Cases: Best Practices", [Read Online](http://ebgconsulting.com/Pubs/Articles/UseCaseBestPractices-Gottesdiener.pdf)

Generally UML[Unified Modeling Language] is used in RUP based projects...[ you do not have to use it ]... So get some insight with UML...

- Alex E. Bell, Death by UML Fever [Read Online](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=984495)

Any process should be customized for your "situations".  If you want to apply it you should create your own-adapted version such as OUP where O stands for "Odiseh" Unified Process :-)
Take a look this:

- Stefan Bergström [ Adopting the Rational Unified Process: Success with the RUP Chapter 1:How to Adopt RUP in Your Project ]  [Read Online](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/samplechapter/0321202945.pdf)

To get more information, you can download online-published version of OpenUP [which is a modifed version of RUP] from http://www.eclipse.org/epf/downloads/configurations/pubconfig_downloads.php

But those are "static info"...Actually we can NOT learn a proccess from books...We have to apply something see what works what does not...We should also able to understand how people behave in teams, what motivates them...etc...

> "Process is only a second-order effect" ...[ should not forget]

That is all!

Comment: Great response on RUP! Hats off to @Novalis.

Answer (score 0):

RUP is not compiling with nowadays business and development environment due to complexion of documentation and time consumption I suggest you take a look at Agile software development method.